# Error with custom form and FieldRenderingControl

Tags: sharepoint-2010

We are trying to create a custom form using the FieldRenderingControl of a field. Everything is fine until we try a new form in a list that isn't in the root site.

So new/edit for list1 in site/ (works)

edit for list2 in site/sites/testsite (works)
new for list2 in site/sites/testsite (does not work)

The error that we are seeing in the uls logs is:
"List does not exist.  The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user."

Here is the code that we are using:

```cs
foreach (SPField f in listOfFields) // cType.Fields)
    {
        var field = f;

        if (item != null)
            field = item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(field.InternalName);

        string uniqueid = field.Id.ToString().Replace("-", "_");
        if (!(field.FieldRenderingControl is TaxonomyFieldControl))
        {
            var editControl = field.FieldRenderingControl;
            editControl.ID = "fld_" + uniqueid; // fix for Lookup picker
            editControl.FieldName = field.InternalName;

            //edit mode if id is provided
            if (item != null)
            {
                editControl.ControlMode = SPControlMode.Edit;
                editControl.ItemId = item.ID;

                var context = SPContext.GetContext(HttpContext.Current, item.ID, list.ID, web);
                editControl.RenderContext = context;
                editControl.ItemContext = context;
            }
            else
            {
                editControl.ControlMode = SPControlMode.New;

                var context = SPContext.GetContext(HttpContext.Current, list.DefaultView.ID, list.ID, web);
                editControl.RenderContext = context;
            }

            editControl.ListId = list.ID;

            this.pnlControls.Controls.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label
            {
                ID = "lbl_" + uniqueid,
                Text = field.Title
            });
            this.pnlControls.Controls.Add(editControl);
       }
  }
```

I can provide more code if needed. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit - From ULS Logs

"List does not exist.  The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user."

```
Stack Trace:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.GetContentTypeThroughQueryString(String strIdx)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.get_ContentTypes()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.ContentTypeInternal(String contentTypeId)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.get_Fields()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.FieldMetadata.get_Field()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.TextField.CreateChildControls()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.BaseFieldControl.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)cc
```

Comment: Provide the full stack trace of the error for better analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I needed to add SPControlMode.New to the context as well as to the FieldRenderingControl.

I changed the code to the following which now works.

```cs
var isNewItem = item == null;

if (isNewItem) item = list.AddItem();

foreach (var f in listOfFields) // cType.Fields)
{
    var field = f;

    if (!isNewItem)
        field = item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(field.InternalName);

    string uniqueid = field.Id.ToString().Replace("-", "_");
    if (!(field.FieldRenderingControl is TaxonomyFieldControl))
    {
        var editControl = field.FieldRenderingControl;
        editControl.ID = "fld_" + uniqueid; // fix for Lookup picker
        editControl.FieldName = field.InternalName;

        //edit mode if id is provided
        if (!isNewItem)
        {
            editControl.ControlMode = SPControlMode.Edit;
            editControl.ItemId = item.ID;

            var context = SPContext.GetContext(HttpContext.Current, item.ID, list.ID, web);
            editControl.RenderContext = context;
            editControl.ItemContext = context;
        }
        else
        {
            editControl.ControlMode = SPControlMode.New;
            editControl.ItemId = item.ID;

            var context = SPContext.GetContext(HttpContext.Current, item.ID, list.ID, web);
            context.FormContext.FormMode = SPControlMode.New;
            editControl.RenderContext = context;
            editControl.ItemContext = context;
        }

        editControl.ListId = list.ID;

        this.pnlControls.Controls.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label
        {
            ID = "lbl_" + uniqueid,
            Text = field.Title
        });
        this.pnlControls.Controls.Add(editControl);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since it works for edit form in site/sites/testsite there is no reason it should not find the list in the new form, more information and context is needed here if you can ....